# PHP: Add custom oracle object in collection parameter of oracle procedure in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

I have a table in oracle 11g

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_DETAIL(  DEGREE     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)  );
```

I want to insert a list of data by procedure . So i have created a custom object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STUDENT_DETAIL_OBJT AS OBJECT(I_STUDENT_DETAIL_DEGREE VARCHAR2 (255));/
```

And a collection

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STUDENT_DETAIL_COLT  AS TABLE OF STUDENT_DETAIL_OBJT; /
```

The collection will be the input parameter of the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SAVE_STUDENT_DETAIL(
I_STUDENT_DETAIL STUDENT_DETAIL_COLT
)
IS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. I_STUDENT_DETAIL.COUNT
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            
        INSERT INTO STUDENT_DETAIL(DEGREE) VALUES(I_STUDENT_DETAIL (i).I_STUDENT_DETAIL_DEGREE);
        COMMIT;
            
        END;
    END LOOP;
END SAVE_STUDENT_DETAIL;
```

In laravel i can call the procedure vaia [Yajra laravel 6](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8)

and the calling the procedure from laravel 6 vaia PDO

```
 $pdo = DB::getPdo();
 $categories = $pdo->getNewCollection('STUDENT_DETAIL_COLT','');
 // if you
 $designaciones = ['0317031','0480458','1925866'];

 foreach ($designaciones as $value) {
       $categories->append($value); // can not ADD STUDENT_DETAIL_OBJT here
 }
 // comment this , will perfectly with 0 Data
 $stmt_rec = $pdo->prepare("begin SAVE_STUDENT_DETAIL(:p1); end;");
 $options = array("type_name" => "STUDENT_DETAIL_COLT","schema" => "");
 $stmt_rec->bindParam(':p1',  $categories, SQLT_NTY, -1, $options);
 $result = $stmt_rec->execute();
 dd($result);
```

My problem is can not create **STUDENT_DETAIL_OBJT** and  add data to collection **STUDENT_DETAIL_COLT** . I am getting follwoing

**OCI-Collection::append(): Unknown or unsupported type of element: 108**

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PDO is limited compared with native extensions such as OCI8. Some of the 'PL/SQL wrapper' techniques in the PL/SQL chapter of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) can be further adapted for use with PDO. Basically you write a PL/SQL procedure that you can call from PDO by binding in scalar values (numbers, strings etc).  The procedure then constructs Oracle objects and does inserts.

And/or use OCI8.